Issue with vfactor in ConTeXt's fraction
I am experiencing an issue with the vfactor option in the \frac command in ConTeXt. Below is a minimal working example:
\startTEXpage[offset=5pt]
  \m{\frac[method=line,vfactor=4000]{c}{c}c}
\stopTEXpage

When I compile this code on context-on-web.eu, the output appears as expected:

However, on my local setup, which uses ConTeXt ver: 2024.02.27 09:18 LMTX fmt: 2024.12.16 on Windows 11 23H2, the numerator does not shift as intended:

Could anyone assist in understanding and resolving this issue? Thank you!

Looks like a bug in the version of ConTeXt included in TeX Live 2024 (2024.02.27). However, this does seem to give the expected output with the LMTX standalone version (2024.11.01).

The logic did change at some point. See the manual for usage that should be up to date. (The change had to do with useless font parameters...)

So the only thing I can do is wait for an update from TeX Live?

If you need to use TL, yes.

@mickep Do you know where the code was changed for this? If it was in Lua or TeX, I can try and cherry-pick it into TL, but if it was in the engine, then that's not really doable.

@MaxChernoff Sorry, I do not remember, but I think the engine was also involved. I think it is better if OP just either 1) installs a stand-alone or 2) figures out the logic in the TL version (I don't think there was a bug, as I remember it, it was only a different logic, depending on font parameters that were usually not really meaningful).
